# Receiving dependency error while installing Ajenti-v-mail on CentOS 7.1

Tags: ajenti

I've installed successfully Ajenti free control panel on my VPS (CentO 7.1). Now I want to install Ajenti V plugin to host websites, databases and email accounts. I am receiving the following error while installing ajenti-v-mail on my VPS. Below is the error  message:

```
Error: Package: ajenti-v-mail-0.1.36-1.noarch (ajenti)
           Requires: courier-authlib-userdb >= 0.64.0
Error: Package: ajenti-v-mail-0.1.36-1.noarch (ajenti)
           Requires: courier-imap >= 4.9.3
```

Please help to solve this error.